# passing through and outputting value to console but not drawing on the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, simulation

There are a few similar questions but none of the answers fix my issue. I am simulating a solar system using canvas. The animation function calls a function to update the positions and then these positions are shown on screen in the form of circles. I have tried not calling the function animate and simply drawing the bodies using the initial conditions and this works fine however when trying to draw them via the animate function nothing is drawn - no even the sun - even though the functions have been passed through.

Why are they not drawing on the canvas?

here is the code (i have removed the for loop which would draw all the planets to only draw the earth just for development purposes, i have also not copied in all the global variables at the top as they take up a lot of space):

```
var massList = [massMecury, massVenus, massEarth, massMars, massJupiter, massSaturn, massUranus, massNeptune];

var xPosList = [initialMecuryXPos, initialVenusXPos, initialEarthXPos, initialMarsXPos, initialJupiterXPos, initialSaturnXPos, initialUranusXPos, initialNeptuneXPos];
var yPosList = [initialMecuryYPos, initialVenusYPos, initialEarthYPos, initialMarsYPos, initialJupiterYPos, initialSaturnYPos, initialUranusYPos, initialNeptuneYPos];
var xVelList = [initialMecuryXVel, initialVenusXVel, initialEarthXVel, initialMarsXVel, initialJupiterXVel, initialSaturnXVel, initialUranusXVel, initialNeptuneXVel];
var yVelList = [initialMecuryYVel, initialVenusYVel, initialEarthYVel, initialMarsYVel, initialJupiterYVel, initialSaturnYVel, initialUranusYVel, initialNeptuneYVel];

//position and velocity scales so they fit on the screen
var posScale = 1.7E10;
//var velScale = 3E9;

var pauseButtonPressed = false;

function axis (){

    var canvas = document.getElementById("solarsys");
    c=canvas.getContext('2d');

    //moves the origin to the centre of the page
    c.translate(400, 275);
    //makes the y axis grow up and shrink down
    c.scale(1,-1);

    //c.fillRect(-innerWidth/2,-innerHeight/2,innerWidth,innerHeight); if want a black background
}

function calAcc(i) {

    //calculates distance between the earth and the sun
    var r = Math.sqrt((xPosList[i]*xPosList[i]) + (yPosList[i]*yPosList[i]));

    //calculates the angle of displacement between the earth and sun
    var theta = Math.atan(yPosList[i]/xPosList[i]);

    //calculate the force on the earth using F = Gm1m2/r^2
    //force is towards the centre of the sun
    var F = (G*massSun*massList[i])/(r*r);

    //correct the angle based on which quadrant it is in
    theta=Math.abs(theta);
    if (xPosList[i] < 0 && yPosList[i] < 0){
        theta = theta;
    } else if (xPosList[i] > 0 && yPosList[i] < 0){
        theta = Math.PI-theta;
    } else if (xPosList[i] > 0 && yPosList[i] > 0){
        theta = theta-Math.PI;
    } else{
        theta = (2*Math.PI)-theta;
    }

    var fX = Math.cos(theta)*F;
    var fY = Math.sin(theta)*F;

    //calculate earths acceleration using Newton 2nd a = F / m 
    var aX = (fX/massList[i]);
    var aY = (fY/massList[i]);

    return [aX, aY];
}

function leapfrog(i) {

    var dt = 5000;

    var a = calAcc(i);

    xVelList[i] = xVelList[i] + (a[0]*dt);
    yVelList[i] = yVelList[i] + (a[1]*dt);

    xPosList[i] = xPosList[i] + (xVelList[i]*dt);
    yPosList[i] = yPosList[i] + (yVelList[i]*dt);

}

function drawBody(i) {
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(xPosList[i]/posScale, yPosList[i]/posScale, 1, 0, twoPi, false);
    c.stroke();
    c.closePath();  

    console.log('body drawn');
}

function drawSun(){
    //draw a yellow circle - the sun
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(0, 0, 2, 0, twoPi, false);
    c.fillStyle = '#ffcc00';
    c.fill();
    c.stroke();
    c.closePath();
}

function animate() {

    var i = 2;

    //for (var i=0; i< xPosList.length; i++){
    leapfrog(i);

    drawBody(i);

    drawSun();

    console.log(xPosList);


    //clears canvas each new loop
    c.clearRect(-innerWidth/2,-innerHeight/2,innerWidth,innerHeight);

}


window.onload=function() {
    axis();

    var looper=setInterval(animate,1);}
```

Comment: Lucy, can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: Do you ever set your canvas width and height? It's not present in your code. And if you don't your first translate(400, 275) will make the origin off of the 300*150 defaults (didn't make the caculations by head but I think nothing in your code would fall there.

Comment: @kaiido i do set the canvas width and heights in the html code

Comment: Could you include it in your question? We need everything that is required in order to reproduce your issue so we can help you. I.e what we call an [MCVE].

Comment: @LajosArpad okay i have this is the link https://jsfiddle.net/lucyclare00/134r5z72/ i don't know if i have done that quite right though

Comment: @Kaiido i have created a JSFiddle as suggested the link is in the comment above

Comment: Troubleshooting is a simplification game, your code is way way to big just practice drawing something... you have comments about colors "draws a blue circle" but I do not see anyplace setting colors

Comment: @HelderSepu sorry that's because i am updating my code to s whole solar system from just a earth-sun simulation which is also why I haven't finished the buttons yet, i am just trying to get a moving simulation before I do any of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems to fix:

1. You have a setInterval which is executed with pauses of 1 milliseconds. This seems to be too quick and I absolutely do not see any guarantee that your browser will be able to draw the things to be drawn.
2. In your animate function you draw things, but instantly remove them. You need to clear the canvas first and only then draw things on the canvas.
3. Your code is very difficult to read, consider refactoring it